# Converting complex number raised to a power to polar form

Tags: complex-numbers

How would one convert $(1+i)^n$ to polar form?

I've heard about de Morgan's law but I don't know how to apply it here.

Comment: *Hint:* Every complex number can be represented as a vector $z=(a; b\imath)$, so the absolute value and the versor (recalling an angle) can be raised separately. Once obtained the two distinct expressions, the versor $[...;...(\vartheta)]$ can be easily converted into Euler's polar form.

Comment: No not eulers form, the trigonometric form

Comment: Then, you've just saved one passage! Once obtained the two raised expressions (versor and absolute value) you've finished.

Comment: It's de Moivre, not de Morgan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(1+i)^n=(\sqrt{2}e^{i\pi/4})^n=2^{n/2}e^{in\pi/4}=2^{n/2}[\cos(n\pi/4)+i\sin(n\pi/4)]$$